# WPF: how to store image in a serializable object with JpegBitmapEncoder and use it again with JpegBitmapDecoder?

Tags: wpf

I have this code to decode a memory stream, but, its not woring, I get this error: 
"No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found."

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(value, false);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                JpegBitmapDecoder JpegBitmapDecoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(
                    stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None,
                    BitmapCacheOption.None);

                image.Source = JpegBitmapDecoder.Frames[0];
                image.Height = hh;
                image.Width = ww;
                stream.Close();
                UIVisual.Background = null;
                UIVisual.Child = image;
                UIVisual.UpdateLayout();
                image = null;
```

And here is how I converted the image to bytes:

```
    JpegBitmapEncoder jpgEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

    jpgEncoder.Frames.Add(bitmapFrame);
    Byte[] _imageArray;
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    jpgEncoder.Save(memStream);
    return memStream.ToArray();
```

so, I store memStream.ToArray() to use it later, I create MemoryStream from the stored memStream.ToArray() and use it with JpegBitmapDecoder like the code above.

Why I can't retrieve the stored bytes ?? is there some wrong I doing ??
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi you have two options return as Byte[] or MemoryStream, see the following code.

Hope it can help

Shalom Keynan

```
    private static  MemoryStream GetImageAsMemoryStream(BitmapSource bitmapSource)
    {
        JpegBitmapEncoder jpgEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        jpgEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
        // Byte[] _imageArray;
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        jpgEncoder.Save(memStream);
        //_imageArray= memStream.ToArray();
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // you MUST rewind before decoding
        return memStream;
     }

    private static Byte[] GetImageAsByte(BitmapSource bitmapSource)
    {
        JpegBitmapEncoder jpgEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        jpgEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
        Byte[] _imageArray;
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        jpgEncoder.Save(memStream);
        _imageArray = memStream.ToArray();
        return _imageArray;
    }
```

good luck!